# Beats Studio 3 bluetooth headset won't work in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio

My Beats Studio 3 bluetooth headset worked fine until an update to ubuntu 20.04 a few weeks ago when they quit working on my computer.  The Beats headset works fine on my Ipad so there is nothing wrong with the head set and another set of bluetooth head set (different brand) works fine on the computer(and the Ipad) which seems to suggest the bluetooth is working on the computer.  I am a relative newbie but I have tried every recommended solution I can find on the internet to no avail.  The problem seems to be related specifically to Beat studio 3 and bluetooh/pulseaudio. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here.  Due to this problem, I am returning these Beats Studio 3 headphones and am instead ordering another set of Anker Soundcore Life Q20 Hybrid Active Noise Cancelling Headphones from Amazon.  I've had them working with Ubuntu before, but they broke within a year of use so this time around I also added the 3-year coverage option.